# marmalade hook for didReceiveRemoteNotification and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, marmalade

I have a marmalade project and running it for iOS.

In case of traditional iOS flow when a user clicks on a notifications the following is called didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and launchOptions has the notification data that I can use.

But in case of marmalade the function registered to S3E_DEVICE_UNPAUSE is called. But there is no notification data passed through.

In short:
How do I have get to know from code (using marmalade sdk) that the user clicked on notification?

Comment: am trying to write an extension that adds observer to UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification -- will update how that goes

Comment: ok obviously this won't work as the extension is called only after the app launch to add observer but by then app has already launched :)

Answer (score 1):

ok found the registered callback

```
s3eIOSNotificationsRegister(S3E_IOSNOTIFICATIONS_REMOTE, OnRemoteNotification, NULL);
```

and also check out s3eIOSNotificationsEventInfo.

https://github.com/marmalade/s3eIOSNotifications

Comment: But this does not work either - cause on app launch the callback is not registered but the app was launched by clicking a notification.